# Compile an 8xk program for TI-84 Plus Silver Edition Calculators

Tags: compiler-construction, ti-basic

I am interested in writing my own app for my TI-84 Plus Silver Edition Calculator (not a program using the calculator's built in language). Does anyone know of a compiler for .8xk files, which are the file extension the TI-84 Apps use? Also, could someone provide me some sample code from an app just to show how hard it is to make one? I have no idea what language is used, and I really want to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to write a flash application is to use TI-BASIC + [Basic Builder](http://www.ticalc.org/archives/files/fileinfo/321/32127.html)

Alternatively, you can take the dive into [z80 Assembly](http://sgate.emt.bme.hu/patai/publications/z80guide/), though the learning curve is very steep. 
Here is some example assembly from [Learning z80 Assembly in 28 Days](http://www.ticalc.org/archives/files/fileinfo/268/26877.html).

```
LD     HL, (stack_ptr)    ; Load stack pointer
LD     (HL), E            ; Push the low-order byte
INC    HL                 ; Move stack pointer to next byte of available space
LD     (HL), D            ; Push the high-order byte
INC    HL
LD     (stack_ptr), HL    ; Save new stack pointer
```

If you would like the speed of assembly with the ease of BASIC, there are several ASM libraries ([xLib](http://www.ticalc.org/archives/files/fileinfo/428/42813.html) for example) available, but I'm not too sure how well they would work as Flash apps.

You might also look into [Axe](http://www.ticalc.org/archives/files/fileinfo/428/42813.html), which is a programming language with near-assembly speeds.